# Ruby-on-Rails post/get parameters value is NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails so I apologize if the answer is obvious.

Here is my routes

```
get 'user_location/show' => 'user_location#show'
```

Form in one of my pages

```
<form action="/user_location/show" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="destination" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Find city" />
</form>
```

Now when I try to print out my post variables on my webpage 
I get null. Something like this

```
<b> The selected destination is </b>
<%params['destination']%>
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it has something to do with routes but I am not too sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try `post 'user_location/show' => 'user_location#show'` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Also make sure you're printing it out `<%= params['destination'] %>` (note the equals sign)

Comment: I get a routing error ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/user_location/show"):

Comment: @TusharChutani, use `match 'user_location/show' => 'user_location#show', via: [:get, :post]`

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing params in your view.

There is typo:

```
<%params['destination']%>
```

should look like

```
<%= params['destination']%>
```

Another suggestion is to use [Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for generating forms.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `POST` method for form submission, so your HTTP Verb for user_location/show have to include `POST` also. So your route would be:

```
match 'user_location/show' => 'user_location#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

And in your view:

```
<%= params['destination'] %>
```